# How do I ensure that my team is verifying all the checklist before responding an email?

Tags: teamwork

We have a checklist that needs to verify before responding back to the customer. However, my team is missing to check the checklist once/twice in a week and those turn out as Quality Escapes. Is there a way to get rid of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Centralize customer handling**

On my team, we have one person who talks to external customers. They do not have all the conversations alone or handle the emails by themselves, but if the customer is communicating with the team, they are in the room or the email is coming from their inbox.

As they are doing it so frequently, they have the procedure memorized and know exactly how to manage their particular expectations.

Assign responsibility for handling the emails to one person, either on a permanent on rotating basis. Create a new email address if you must.

**You could also build yourself an Outlook plugin/Chrome extension**

That extension would generate a popup box whenever a client with an email on a specific list was being messaged reminding them to check the checklist. Unless you have a massive organization though, this is probably a bit far.

Comment: thank you so much Matthew for the tip and it chrome extension seems promising.
Can you direct me on how do I create a Chrome Extension? Is there any tutorial?

Comment: "build an extension to solve the problem" is the most developer-centric and unusable advice you can give

Comment: @rocky09 https://dev.to/mikeeus/building-gmailchrome-extension-with-vuejs-and-inboxsdk-20ah might this do?

Comment: @bharal but OP is a developer.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the value of the quality escapes. To a lesser extent, it depends on the volume of emails generally sent out.

Most obviously, you can have a manager review all outbound communications, so your individual members will send their proposed message the manager, and they will ok it.

If it is too much effort/too high a workload for a manager, having the communique reviewed by another team member will also work.

Having a pre-filled template that team members use to answer questions might also help. They cut/paste the template in and then modify as needed. Team members might well have their *own* manager-approved template, that covers the same checklist but allows each person to express themselves in their own manner. This will avoid the feeling of talking to a robot.

You can combine these as needed.